# Editing text in Excel: Paste a '-' before each word in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large excel file containing multiple words per cell. Like this:

```
       A1
1    Word 1
     Word2
     Word e 3

2    Word 1
     Word2
     Words3
```

I want to place a '-' before each word in the cell, so the result must be:

```
     A1
1    -Word 1
     -Word2
     -Word e 3

2    -Word 1
     -Word2
     -Words3
```

I do not want to split the words in to separate cells in order for it to work.
Been fiddling with it for a while, but i cant find a function/solution that does the job without splitting the words into separate cells.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *might* be able to do it a function, but it'd be large and cumbersome. IMO, best approach would be to write a vba sub that did. Also, would be best practice to format the target cells as text (as a leading '-' in any other format evokes an error if/when manually edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
="-"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&"-")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It almost works, but the words resulting from the function appear side by side instead of below each other. Strange thing is that in google sheets it does work! Is there a way to also make this work in Windows Excel?

Comment: you need to with the cell(s) selected, click wrap text on the tool bar.

Comment: I feel terrible... Many thanks for the code, it works perfectly.